# In Perl, how to avoid opening files multiple times

Tags: file, loops, perl

I need to read from a file, iterate through it and write the line to another file. When the number of lines reach a threshold, close the output file handle and open a new one.

How do I avoid opening and closing the output file handle every time I read a line from the input file handle as below?

```
use autodie qw(:all);

my $tot       = 0;
my $postfix   = 'A';
my $threshold = 100;

open my $fip, '<', 'input.txt';
LINE: while (my $line = <$fip>) {
    my $tot += substr( $line, 10, 5 );       
    open my $fop, '>>', 'output_' . $postfix; 
    if ( $tot < $threshold ) {
        print {$fop} $line;
    }
    else {
        $tot = 0;
        $postfix++;
        redo LINE;
    }
    close $fop;
}
close $fip;
```

Comment: Don't open and close your file inside the for loop.  Move the `open` command above the for loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only reopen the file when you change `$postfix`. Also, you can get a bit simpler.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie qw(:all);

my $tot       = 0;
my $postfix   = 'A';
my $threshold = 100;

open my $fop, '>>', 'output_' . $postfix; 
open my $fip, '<', 'input.txt';
while (my $line = <$fip>) {
    $tot += substr( $line, 10, 5 );       

    if ($tot >= $threshold) {
        $tot = 0;
        $postfix++;
        close $fop;
        open $fop, '>>', 'output_' . $postfix; 
    }
    print {$fop} $line;
}
close $fip;
close $fop;
```

Comment: +1 but I think you should only keep the second part of your answer.

Comment: And you can add at the bottom:  `if(tell($fop) != -1) { close $fop; }` to close it.

Comment: You should always error check when you open files. Unless, of course, you are using the `autodie` module. Which you are. :)

Comment: @Tiger-222, `$fop` should always be open at the end of the program, so I think a standard `close` should be fine.  In a small script like this, not bothering to close at all and letting Perl worry about the cleanup would be fine, too.

Comment: Yes you're right, a simple `close` is enough; I would just point it ;)